# Calling static nested(depth >= 2) method

Tags: c#, .net

I have written a small code.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Nested.Nested2.DoSomething();
    }

    class Nested
    {
        public class Nested2
        {
            public static void DoSomething()
            { }
        }
    }
}
```

There is class `Program` which has nested class `Nested`. Class `Nested` have nested class too - `Nested2` with static method `DoSomething()`.

In `Main` I call `DoSomething()`.

**My question:** Why can I call this method in `Main`. I know that method is `static` and if this method were inside `Nested` class (not `Nested2`) I could call it. Why don't I need to create instance of `Nested` and then call this method like this:

```
Nested nested = new Nested();
nested.Nested2.DoSomething();
```

Why can I access `Nested2` (`Nested.Nested2`) without creating instance of `Nested` if `Nested2` is not `static`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can call a static method on a non-static class. I'm not sure why you would expect this to change if you nest it inside another class.

Comment: You don't need instance to access `static` members.

Comment: It's a *static* method, why would you need an instance? `Nested.Nested2` is the name of the class. `DoSomething` is the name of the nested method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The complete name of your inner class is actually `Nested.Nested2`. In this case `Nested` does not refer to an actual instance of the class `Nested` nor to any static member, but can be considered as namespace.

The same also applies to `Nested`, which is actually called `Program.Nested` when outside your `Program`-class. Creating instances thus goes with (assuming `Nested` was `public`, which it isn´t in your case):

```
var instance = new Program.Nested();
```

Or for your `Nested2`-class within `Program`:

```
var instance = new Nested.Nested2();
```

Or for your `Nested2`-class from outside `Program`:

```
var instance = new Program.Nested.Nested2();
```

This has nothing to do with your members nor classes beeing static but with the fact of the actual *name* of the class.

Comment: Thank you,  I misunderstood `Nested.Nested2` statement. I thought about nesting, but it is about class name. Now I understand. Thanks so much.

Comment: This won't work: `var instance = new Program.Nested();` because `Nested` is not public.

Comment: @Roma Yeap, you´re right. I hope readers will get what I ment anyway.